Possible Thread Starvation in C++
I have a decode function that decodes a string and internally uses a map to store already-decoded values for efficiency. This function is accessed by multiple threads (using pthread), so to prevent concurrent access issues with the map, I added a std::mutex. However, after adding the mutex, I noticed that some threads eventually stop working or appear to get stuck. When I removed the mutex locks, all threads ran without any issues.
My question is: Could this be a case of starvation? How can I resolve this?
Additional Context: This C++ code is being used in an Android application via JNI.
std::unordered_map<std::string, std::pair<int, std::vector<uint8_t>>> decoded_map;
std::mutex decoded_map_mutex;

const char* decode(const char* encodedString) {
    std::string encoded(encodedString);
    std::string decoded;
    
    for (/* some condition */) {
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(decoded_map_mutex);
            // Operation involving map search
            auto it = decoded_map.find(part);
            if (it != decoded_map.end()) {
                // Some processing
            }
        }
        // Additional processing
        {
            std::lock_guard<std::mutex> lock(decoded_map_mutex);
            decoded_map[part] = std::make_pair(index / 4, bytes);
        }
        
        decode += part;
    }

    return strdup(decoded.c_str());
}


A side note: prefer std::thread over pthread.

First question I have is why mix pthread and std::mutex, and not use std::thread (or std::jthread) instead? Also multithreading is already hard, mixing technologies can make it even harder.  But what strikes me most is that you lock and unlock twice in one function (which might be ok, but not something I see often). And chekcking a condition outside a lock seems risky too.

All in all what you show us is not a minimum reproducible example (the condition you check must access some global variable for instance (not recommended) and there is no code showing how that's updated and from which threads.

@PepijnKramer I have just started with multithreading in c++. I do not know much about the differences in using std::thread and pthread. can you explain which one to use when and why?. Taking about the condition it is just a simple for loop which takes a fix length of encoded string, performs some arithmetics on it and store the encoded part against the decoded part in the map

@wohlstad same question to you as well

pthread is a "C" style api for controlling threads, std::thread is from C++\s own library (and will be portable to other OS's).  So the condition is only accessed by the calling thread then?

What you know need to do is debug, e.g. break when your code is blocked, and see if you have a deadlock. Check all your threads and which mutexes they are waiting on

@Ghost Comparing pthreads to std::thread is out of the scope for a comment here, but I would say that as a rule of thumb if you are using C++ (and not C) always prefer std::thread.

@PepijnKramer Yes, The condition is only used by the calling thread. Only the global map & mutex shared in code snippet is being used by all the threads.

e.g. break when your code is blocked what do you mean by this?

Attach your debugger and wait until the program is not doing anything anymore. And then check all the callstacks of all the threads and check which ones are blocked on which mutexes.  Being able to debug like this is essential if you're starting with multi-threading.

okay thanks! I'll try using a debugger

can I use pthread_mutex_lock?

using debugger is not feasible for me

If you don't understand threading that well, don't roll your own. This question has some excellent suggestions, most notably folly::concurrenthashmap

C++20 has provided std::jthread as an improvement over C++11 std::thread. Even if you didn't intend to use C++(you're doing anyway), C11 has threads.h with thrd_t. pthread is considered too low-level. The snippet provided, doesn't give much of a context about your problem. One probable problem is dead-lock resulting from locking multiple mutexs in different orders.

How many threads?  Most of the code looks like it is running while the mutex is locked, this will effectively single-thread the program.   Also a thread that has just released a mutex is more likely to retake a mutex as it is still in it's time-slice.  There is no "fare" mutex in C++ or pthreads you will need to role your own.

@RichardCritten There are around 5 to 10 threads. How can I implement a fair mutex? do you have any resources?

Sorry the "fare" mutex point is a distraction.  A thread needs to do a significant amount of work with no mutex locked (preferably a time-slice or more, or some IO).  The above code looks like it does no significant work when the mutex is unlocked effectively single-threading the program

@RichardCritten Thanks you for your reply!
can you share any resource related to concurrency control or threads in c++ ?

@all one thing I figured it out that I am forking my process using fork syscall and when I call decode function from that child process then this scenario occurs

Do not call fork from a program that has more than one live thread. fork kills all of the threads in the child process other than the one that called it.

so you mean if I have 5 threads started from the main thread & If I call fork from one of the thread, the rest four thread will be killed?

Do not call fork from a program that has more than one live thread. The Android OS is based on the Linux kernel, and the man 2 fork page from Linux says this:
   •  The child process is created with a single thread—the one that
      called fork().  The entire virtual address space of the parent
      is replicated in the child, including the states of mutexes,
      condition variables, and other pthreads objects; the use of
      pthread_atfork(3) may be helpful for dealing with problems
      that this can cause.

   •  After a fork() in a multithreaded program, the child can
      safely call only async-signal-safe functions (see
      signal-safety(7)) until such time as it calls execve(2).

All of the threads except the one that called fork will vanish from the child process. If any of them had a mutex locked, then that mutex will stay locked, with no way to unlock it. If any of them had work-in-progress, that work will be unfinished, with no way (in general) for you to know how much of it was done.
You asked, in a comment:

so you mean if I have 5 threads started from the main thread & If I call fork from one of the thread, the rest four thread will be killed?

After the fork call, the parent process still will have five threads, but the child process will have only one.

so the threads in the parent process will continue to work as intended. but in my case my calling thread has acquired the lock and my remaining threads are getting stuck

@Ghost, If fork does anything to the parent process, then that's something I can't explain, and this "answer" doesn't really answer your question. But my point is, forking a multi-threaded process leaves you with a broken child process. Don't do it! I'm going to hand this "answer" over to the community, and leave it here as an extended comment.

okay thank you for answer, I am leaving this question as unanswered for a while to get more inputs from the community
