Parent process thread gets stuck
I have implemented C++ code (for Android) that uses multithreading. There is a function that decodes a string, utilizing std::mutex and std::lock_guard to protect a shared resource (std::unordered_map) accessed within the function. This decoding function is used by multiple threads.
Problem: Suppose I have created 5 threads (T1...T5). Threads T1, T2, T3, and T4 use the decode function, while T5 does not. When T2 forks a child process and uses the decode function, after some time, T1 and T3 stop working (or seem to be stuck), while all other threads continue to function.
My question: What could be the reason for this behavior? From what I have read, if a multithreaded program forks, any thread in the child process might get stuck if it encounters a mutex in a locked state.

Instead of describing the code, you should post it as copy-pasted text, in a form of a [mre] (with emphasis on minimial).

fork is not std C++; it's a POSIX function for UNIX family of OS. AFAIK, fork must be invoked before any thread creation; calling it after creating any threads is UB, and you are doing it from within a worker thread. Read the docs before using anything.

What's the problem statement that you are trying to solve?

Same as https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78976568/possible-thread-starvation-in-c  ?

@Red.Wave said, "UB." In case you do not know,  that stands for "undefined behavior." What it means is, if your program depends on UB, then there is no authoritative answer to any question about how it behaves. If your investigation of some problem reveals UB--even if the UB seems to be in an entirely different part of the program--you must get rid of the UB before you can trust any explaination of why your program does what it does.

Presumably, if your program forks a child process, then there must be some communication between the two processes. Otherwise, what would be the point? Even if the fork() call had no direct consequence for the parent, the parent will then try to communicate with a child process that is in a UB-damaged state. What could possibly go wrong? (Note: that's not a rhetorical question! I'm seriously asking you to think about what happens when the parent communicate with another process when it is not possible to give any truthful explanation about what the other process actually is doing.)

basically this forked process is used for attaching to the parent threads to avoid debugger to connect
